# Importing a python class from different package

Tags: python

This is my python project structure,

```
    test

       cat

         Cat.py

           class Cat
       dog

         Dog.py

           class Dog
```

I got module not found error when importing Dog class into Cat class

from dog.Dog import *

How to fix it?

Comment: Are the files in the same folder or are they in separate folders 'cat' and 'dog'?

Comment: You need to add a file called `__init__.py` to the directory to turn it into a package that Python recognises.

Comment: those files stored under test folder

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing concepts, use:

```
from dog import Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
from dog import Dog
```

or

```
from dog import *
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the syntax,

```
# To import a module
import [module]

# To import a class from a module
from [module] import [class]
```

Hence, in your case,

```
# To import a class [Dog] from a module [dog]
from dog import Dog

# To import everything from the module [dog]
import dog             # -> Refer your class as dog.Dog
from dog import *      # -> Refer your class directly as Dog
import dog as d        # -> Refer your class as d.Dog
```